# Sorting arrays in method and returning to main method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods, return

Read an array of 5 integer values in the main method. Create a separate function that will sort the array and return the array back to the main method and print it there.

So far I have done:

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class arraysort {
        public static void main(String[]args) {
           Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter 5 integers: ");
           int [] x = new int [5];
           for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
               x[i] = in.nextInt();
           }
        }
        public static int sortarray(int [] value) {

            int max = value[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
//I am not sure after this point 
//I just did the rest
                int [] y = new int [5];
                Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
                value[i] = in.nextInt();
                Arrays.sort(y);
                System.out.println(y);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you writing sort yourself because this is homework?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29

Comment: Do you even know how methods work? and return types?

Comment: I now see that Arrays.sort is in the code actually. I don't understand what you're trying to do, you're creating a new array at every iteration of the for loop, and trying to sort an array which has only 1 initialized value.

Comment: I think you should try reading [these tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). They will help you in many issues.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use this sortArray if you don't want to use built in methods:

```
 public static int[] sortarray(int [] value) 
{
  for (int arrayIterator = 0; arrayIterator < value.length; arrayIterator++)  
{  
  for(int iterator2=arrayIterator+1;iterator2<value.length;iterator2++){  
                if(value[iterator2]<value[arrayIterator]){  
                    int temp=value[arrayIterator];  
                value[arrayIterator]=value[iterator2];  
                    value[iterator2]=temp;  
                }  
            }   
         }  return value;     
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code sponsored by [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) and [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
public class ArraySort 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int t[] = {3, 5, 2}; // your reading part is fine, so I will skip it
        sortArrayWithoutCheating(t);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
    }

    public static void sortArrayWithoutCheating(int[] t)
    {
        // simplest O(n^2) sort
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (t[i] < t[j])
                {
                    // swap t[i] and t[j]
                    int temp = t[i];
                    t[i] = t[j];
                    t[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void sortArray(int[] t)
    {
        Arrays.sort(t);
    }
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/RQRMnJ):

```
[2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: I believe the OP isn't allowed to use a method found within the API to sort the array for him; he has to write the method himself. Also, in your `sortArray(int[])` method, what is the point of returning an `int[]`?

Comment: @JoshM Thanks, I've improved my answer.